# Creating a function to filter a dataframe based on a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, dictionary

I am new coding in Python and I'm facing an issue.

I've a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'brand':['Ford','fiat', 'opel'], 'year':[2016,2016,2017]})
```

Which I want to filter by a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'color':'red', 'year':2016}
```

I can filter using this:

```
df.loc[np.all(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d), axis=1)]
```

But when I try to put this last statement on a function, it doesn't work anymore and I get "none" as result. Anyone knows where are my mistakes?

my code:

[image]

Comment: You need to `return` the new dataframe in your function: `def some_function(df):
    return df.loc[np.all(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d), axis=1)]`

Comment: you forgot to return

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to get the output:

(1) print it in the function. Use this if you only need to visualise or to check the output:

```
def filtro(df, **d):
    df = df.loc[np.all(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d), axis=1)]
    print(df)

filtro(df, **d)

  color brand  year
0   red  Ford  2016
```

(2) use return statement (as suggested by @mozway and @NuriTaş. Use this if you need the output for subsequent steps or downstream operations:

```
def filtro(df, **d):
    df = df.loc[np.all(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d), axis=1)]
    return df

df1 = filtro(df, **d)
print(df1)

  color brand  year
0   red  Ford  2016
```